# Mongoose Path "." is required - problem with PostmanMocking?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman

i am testing my mongoose (for MongoDB) schema, and I encountered an validation issue. After making POST verb I am getting en error:

```
    "message": {
        "errors": {
            "number": {
                "message": "Path `number` is required.",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `number` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "number"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "number"
            }
        },
        "_message": "eventArrayModel validation failed",
        "message": "eventArrayModel validation failed: number: Path `number` is required.",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
```

This is my mocked json in Postman: 
[JSON mocked file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POYz2.png)

```
{
    "arrayName": "displayedEvents",
    "number": "4"
}
```

And this is my mongoose schema:

```
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const  eventSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    //    required: true,
    },
    start: {
        type: Date,
     //   required: true,
    },
    end: {
        type: Date,
     //   required: true,
    },
    allDay: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    resource: {
        type: String,
      //  required: true,
    },
});

const eventArrayModel = mongoose.model("eventArrayModel", {
    arrayName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
   array: {type: [eventSchema]} ,
   number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    }
});

module.exports = eventArrayModel;
```

And the get router:

```
router.get('/',  async (req,res)=> {
try{
    const posts = await eventArrayModel.find();
    res.json(posts);

}catch(err){
    res.json({message: err});
}
```

});

I can't see anything wrong about this code. It works fine without number field.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I found it, this part of code

```
router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{
  const post = new eventArrayModel({
      arrayName: req.body.arrayName
  });
  try {
      const savedPost = await post.save();
      res.json(savedPost);
  }catch(err){
      res.json({message: err});
  }

});
```

Should looks more like this:

```
router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{
  const post = new eventArrayModel({
      arrayName: req.body.arrayName,
      array: req.body.array,
      myNumber: req.body.myNumber
  });
  try {
      const savedPost = await post.save();
      res.json(savedPost);
  }catch(err){
      res.json({message: err});
  }

});
```